# R rbind: concatenate each element of a nested list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm having hard times trying to concatenate data.frames that are elements of a list of lists in R. I have implented a first raw solution with a for-loop, but (of course) it becomes really slow as the length of the list grow.

(UPDATE: I have added the element "message" to each nested list)

Here the example code:

```
list1 = list()
list1[[1]] = list(df = data.frame(A = 1 : 10, B = 30 : 21), 
                  message = "first list")
list1[[2]] = list(df = data.frame(A = 11 : 20, B = 20 : 11), 
                  message = "second list")
list1[[3]] = list(df = data.frame(A = 21 : 30, B = 30 : 21), 
                  message = "third list")

dfFinal = data.frame()
for(nIndexList in 1 : length(list1)) {
  dfFinal = rbind(dfFinal, list1[[nIndexList]]$df)
}
```

Is there a faster way to do that (e.g., vectorization)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**

Based on the new requirement - each sublist now contains a dataframe *and* a vector - we must filter for `data.frame`s

```
do.call(rbind, c(Filter(is.data.frame, unlist(list1, recursive = FALSE)),
                 make.row.names = FALSE))
```

---

**initial answer** (each sublist contained a sinlge dataframe only)

You might use `unlist` with argument `recursive = FALSE` and then `do.call(rbind, ...)`

```
do.call(rbind, c(unlist(list1, recursive = FALSE), make.row.names = FALSE))
#    A  B
#1   1 30
#2   2 29
#3   3 28
#4   4 27
#5   5 26
#6   6 25
#7   7 24
#8   8 23
#9   9 22
#10 10 21
#11 11 20
# ...
```

`make.row.names = FALSE` is passed to `rbind` as well.

---

If speed is a concern you might use `data.table`

```
data.table::rbindlist(unlist(list1, recursive = FALSE))
```

---

A `tidyverse` way would be

```
dplyr::bind_rows(purrr::flatten(list1))
```

Comment: thanks, it works. However, my case is a bit more difficult: each nested list has more than one element and the solution you provide does not work. 
Should I update my first question or open a new thread?